# How can I scroll up my DataGridview when I click the content?

Tags: c#, scroll, datagridview

My table has many rows. I keeps some row numbers.

When I click No.3 , I want to display my table from No.3 and No. 1 and 2 must be scroll up.

But whatever I do, it is showing from 1,2,3, and can't can't scroll..
I want to write by using DataGrid_ItemClick(){}.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery `.scrollTop(value)` the page can be scrolled to the row entered. Here is a [detailed way](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to use it If you are using datagrid in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    }
```

It will work no matter how the selection modes are set or whether the user holds ctrl or shift..